# How to add groupBy().count() to the source DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe:

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|        column0|       column1|       column2|label|
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+
```

I want to apply groupBy and count on it and make the following result:

```
+--------------+--------------+-----+
|       column1|       column2|count|
+--------------+--------------+-----+
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|   19|
| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|   10|
+--------------+--------------+-----+
```

I know that I have to use this:

```
dataFrame_Train.groupBy("column1", "column2").count().show()
```

However the problem is that **I need to add "count" column as a permanent column to my dataframe.** 
In the above case, if I use `dataFrame_Train.show()` after the `groupBy`, I see the first dataframe without "count" column. This code:

```
dataFrame_Train.groupBy("column1", "column2").count().show()
`dataFrame_Train.show()`
```

Can you help me to add `groupBy("column1", "column2").count()` to the dataframe? (Since I need to use "count" column for training the data in future) Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@eliasah's answer is fine, but *might* not be the most effective, code- and performance-wise.

### Window Aggregate Functions (aka Window Aggregations)

Whenever you see a need for `groupBy` and `join`, esp. for such a simple use case like this, think of **window aggregate functions**.

The main difference between `groupBy` and window aggregations is that the former gives you at most the number of rows as in the source dataset while the latter (window aggregates) gives you **exactly** the number of rows as in the source dataset. That seems to match your requirements exactly, *doesn't it?*

With that, let's see the code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val columns1and2 = Window.partitionBy("column1", "column2") // <-- matches groupBy

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
// using count aggregate function over entire partition frame
val counts = ips.withColumn("count", count($"label") over columns1and2)
scala> counts.show
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+-----+
|        column0|       column1|       column2|label|count|
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+-----+
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604900|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604899|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|    2|   13|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|    7|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|    7|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|    7|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|    7|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|    7|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|    7|
|05:49:56.604908| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|    2|    7|
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-----+-----+
```

*Done!* Clean and easy. That's my beloved window aggregate functions!

### Performance Comparison

Now, comes the fun part. Is the difference between this and @eliasah's solutions just pure syntax? I don't think so (yet I'm still learning how to draw right conclusions). See the execution plans and judge yourself.

The following is the execution plan for window aggregation.

[image]

The following however is the execution plan for `groupBy` and `join` (I had to take two screenshots as the plan was too big to include in one).

[image]
[image]

Job-wise `groupBy` and `join` query beats window aggregation easily, 2 Spark jobs for the former while 5 for the latter.

Operator-wise, their number and most importantly Exchanges (which are Spark SQL's shuffles), window aggregation may have beaten `groupBy` with `join`.

Comment: Job-wise and operator-wise are interesting but wall-clock-time-wise what is faster?

Answer (score 4):

We will use the same data that you have presented in `csv` format.

Let's read those data :

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("csv").load("data.txt").toDF("column0","column1","column2","label")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column0: string, column1: string ... 2 more fields]
```

We can now perform our group by aggregations :

```
scala> val df2 = df.groupBy("column1","column2").count
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column1: string, column2: string ... 1 more field]
```

All we need to do is an equi-join on the same columns you performed the group by key on :

```
scala> val df3 = df.join(df2, Seq("column1","column2"))
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [column1: string, column2: string ... 3 more fields]
```

Et voilà !

```
scala> df3.show
+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----+-----+                     
|       column1|       column2|        column0|label|count|
+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----+-----+
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604899|    2|   13|
| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|05:49:56.604908|    2|    7|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604900|    2|   13|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604899|    2|   13|
| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|05:49:56.604908|    2|    7|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604900|    2|   13|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604899|    2|   13|
| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|05:49:56.604908|    2|    7|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604900|    2|   13|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604899|    2|   13|
| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|05:49:56.604908|    2|    7|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604900|    2|   13|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604899|    2|   13|
| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|05:49:56.604908|    2|    7|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604900|    2|   13|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604899|    2|   13|
| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|05:49:56.604908|    2|    7|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604900|    2|   13|
|10.0.0.2.54880| 10.0.0.3.5001|05:49:56.604899|    2|   13|
| 10.0.0.3.5001|10.0.0.2.54880|05:49:56.604908|    2|    7|
+--------------+--------------+---------------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Very clever! I like this!